# My Blog Home page thumbnails suddenly turned blurry but other images are fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs, blogger

This is my blog http://www.dateswithdanie.com hosted on blogger. Some days ago the images next to the post titles on the home page just turned blurry. I've tried and tried to fix it, searched for solutions everywhere. It's surprising cause it was working fine, I didn't tamper with the code and suddenly things just changed. Please help me with a solution as I'm frustrated really, Thank you.

Code -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
            <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
              &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
              </div>
             </div>
            <b:else/>
            <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
              <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
                &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<data:post.firstImageUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                </div>
              </div>
              <b:else/>
              <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
                &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                </div>
               </div>
            </b:if></b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
            <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
              &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
              </div>
             </div>
            <b:else/>
            <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
              <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
                &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<data:post.firstImageUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                </div>
             </div>
              <b:else/>
              <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
                &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                </div>
              </div>
            </b:if></b:if>
 </b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your theme code is using JavaScript to change the dimensions of the thumbnail image. But due to some error (as seen in the browser console), that is no longer functioning. A better approach would be to use the Blogger's native image resizing operator `resizeImage` to change the image dimensions. The above code will change as follows -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
        <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
          &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 370)' />) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
          </div>
         </div>
        <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
          <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
            &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.firstImageUrl, 370)' />) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            </div>
          </div>
          <b:else/>
          <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
            &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            </div>
           </div>
        </b:if></b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
        <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
          &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.thumbnailUrl, 370)' />) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
          </div>
         </div>
        <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
          <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
            &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<b:eval expr='resizeImage(data:post.firstImageUrl, 370)' />) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            </div>
         </div>
          <b:else/>
          <div class='block-image'><div class='thumb'>
            &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            </div>
          </div>
        </b:if></b:if>
</b:if>
```

Comment: @DaniellaBature I implemented the above changes in a demo blog - http://saifyv1.blogspot.com/ and they work without issue. I checked your site  http://www.dateswithdanie.com but couldn't find the width 370 for images, have you removed the changes that you tried from your site?

Comment: it finally worked. I tried it on another computer, I guess my other laptop has a problem. I feel like fainting right now. Thank you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Image uploaded is too small 72X72 for container and that with css **background-size** cover will try stretch to container size. So try using bigger image as per the container width

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: the image is already set to original size, it wasn't reduced in any way. All images

Answer (score 0):

Yes,its common to all blogger users.The best thing to do is not to keep going into 'visit profile' or 'my profile' often after the upload of your picture was completed.It does change only when you go into 'visit profile'link and not otherwise.

Comment: I don't do anything special when I'm uploading images from my computer.